# Solving $\frac13\int_0^\alpha\int_0^\frac{\pi}2{\big(\frac{a\sin\phi+\sqrt{{\sin\phi}^2(a^2-bC)+C}}{1-b{\sin\phi}^2}\big)^3\sin\phi d\phi d\theta}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates, trigonometric-integrals

So, I came to this problem: to model a HALF cone volume using spherical coordinates in a way I can slice this half cone volume in any way I want and get a result.

After 3 weeks of no social life, I finally found the equation that rules the behavior of the slice, or, in other words, "Rho" ($\rho$). After finding $\rho$, the next step was to double integrate $(1/3)\rho^{3}\sin(\varphi)\mathrm{d}\varphi\mathrm{d}\theta)$ to get the volume I wanted.

The final equation was so tricky and I was so exhausted of the task that I had to use $1/3$ Composite Simpson Rule for Double Integrals and make 3,600 iterations to get close to the results, as I couldn't calculate the error (4th derivative was even harder to get).

Well, the job is done, client is satisfied, but the double integration is getting into my head and I don't believe I will ever see a swift and elegant equation of this half cone volume. But, who knows.

For the ones who want to dare to solve the equation and get the prize, here it is:

$$\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left(\frac{a\sin{\phi}+\sqrt{{\sin{\phi}}^2\left(a^2-bC\right)+C}}{1-b{\sin{\phi}}^2}\right)^3\sin{\phi}\mathrm{d}\phi\mathrm{d}\theta}$$

where as

$a = B\sin{\theta}-n\cos{\theta}$

$b = A{\sin{\theta}}^2$

*Attending Paul's request where $A=1+1/k^2,B=(nk-w)/k^2,C=w/k(w/k-n^2)$

** $R$ value in the circle equation is variable in Y-Axis

[image: sketch]

$A\ =\ 1+\frac{1}{k^2}$

$B\ =\ \frac{nk-w}{k^2}$

$C\ =\ \frac{w}{k}\left(\frac{w}{k}-2n\right)$

[image: diagram]

Comment: Maybe a diagram will help visualising the context? Anyway tough luck

Comment: Sure. Diagram added

Comment: Why spherical coordinates? Cylindrical coordinates with the $z$-axis being the center axis of the cone would surely be easier. Is that "random slice" a plane that is slicing the cone? Since you call the vertical axis the "cone radius", does that mean the axis of revolution is the horizontal axis? Defining "$a, b$" in terms of $A$ and $B$ is only useful when you've bothered to define $A$ and $B$. But those definitions are the only place $A, B$ appear in your post. $C$ also shows up in your integrals without any hint of an explanation.

Comment: Hi Paul. I tried cylindrical coordinates in the way you said, the classic solution "Cone cut by a plane" where you can find in every book (also in this community), but failed to develop the equation as my results were very poor and didn't match the reality. I have a vague memory why was that. Taking the z axis with cone formula below and plane formula above was not working for me. But I remember myself trying another method and enter deeper and deeper into spherical coordinates, as calculations were making sense and getting the results I wanted to. I'll review my post to make it clearer.